# JSONB ignores Jackson serialization inclusion

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jackson, jsonb

I'd like to persist to jsonb type column (com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType)

```
@Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(name = "style", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
private TextStyleJsonB style;
```

JSON object is relative big and i don't want that it saving fields with null values, so i decided to use custom object mapper, where i ignore null values. But it was not applied and all null values still saved to postgres database.
Any idea how to get rid of null fields and save only fields with real value?

In spring boot i have following application properties

```
hibernate:
  types:
    jackson:
      object:
        mapper: com.xxx.constructor.configurations.CustomObjectMapperSupplier
```

CustomObjectMapperSupplier looks like this:

```
public class CustomObjectMapperSupplier
    implements ObjectMapperSupplier {

  @Override
  public ObjectMapper get() {
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    return mapper;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson ObjectMapper setSerializationInclusion() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406817/jackson-objectmapper-setserializationinclusion-not-working)

Comment: no, it has nothing to do with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the CustomObjectMapperSupplier in your application.yml, you should create an hibernate.properties file with the property:

```
hibernate.types.jackson.object.mapper=com.xxx.constructor.configurations.CustomObjectMapperSupplier
```