# ObjectMapper convert class to map

Tags: java, jackson

ObjectMapper convert class to map , I'm in trouble.
I have a util class. like this.

```
    @Slf4j
    public class JsonUtil {
        private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
        static {
            objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
            javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
            javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
            objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
            objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        }
        public static Map<String, Object> toMap(Object obj) {
            try {
                return objectMapper.convertValue(obj, new TypeReference<>() {
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("failed：", e);
                return Map.of();
            }
        }
    
        public static Map<String, Object> toMapIgnoreNull(Object obj) {
            try {
                return objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                        .convertValue(obj, new TypeReference<>() {
                        });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("failed：", e);
                return Map.of();
            }
        }
    }
```

**`toMapIgnoreNull`** method appears to be converting an object to a map while ignoring null values. It uses an **`ObjectMapper`** from Jackson to achieve this. Here's a breakdown of what it does:

1. It sets the serialization inclusion to **`NON_NULL`**, which means that null values will not be included in the resulting JSON.
2. It converts the given object to a map using **`convertValue`** method of the **`ObjectMapper`**.

If any exception occurs during this process, it catches the exception, logs the error message, and returns an empty map.

This **`toMap`** method is also used to convert an object into a map, but it doesn't ignore null values. It also utilizes the **`ObjectMapper`** from the Jackson library. Here's a detailed explanation of the method:

1. It uses the **`convertValue`** method of the **`ObjectMapper`** to convert the given object into a map.
2. If any exceptions occur during this process, it catches the exception, logs the error message, and returns an empty map.

Compared to the previous method, this one doesn't filter out null values but retains all key-value pairs from the object, even if the value is null.

when

```
@Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
    static class User {
        private String username;
        private String password;
    }

    public static void johnOut() {
        User john = new User();
        john.setUsername("John");
        Map<String, Object> johnMap = toMap(john);
        System.out.println("result 1: " + johnMap);
        Map<String, Object> JohnIgnoreNullMap = toMapIgnoreNull(john);
        System.out.println("result 2: " + JohnIgnoreNullMap);
    }

    private static void jimOut() {
        User jim = new User();
        jim.setUsername("jim");
        Map<String, Object> jimIgnoreNullMap = toMapIgnoreNull(jim);
        System.out.println("result 3: " + jimIgnoreNullMap);
        Map<String, Object> jimMap = toMap(jim);
        System.out.println("result 4: " + jimMap);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        johnOut();
        jimOut();
    }
```

```
when `johnOut()` is in front, the console prints:

result 1: {username=John, password=null}
result 2: {username=John, password=null}
result 3: {username=jim, password=null}
result 4: {username=jim, password=null}

but when `jimOut()` is in front, the console prints:

result 3: {username=jim}
result 4: {username=jim}
result 1: {username=John}
result 2: {username=John}

why?

expectation：
result 1: {username=John, password=null}
result 2: {username=John, password=null}
result 3: {username=jim}
result 4: {username=jim}
or

result 3: {username=jim}
result 4: {username=jim}
result 1: {username=John, password=null}
result 2: {username=John, password=null}

Is there any experience that can help me？
```

Comment: Your expectations seem wrong. Both test methods call `toMap` and `toMapIgnoreNull` so results 2 and 3 should have nulls while result 1 and 4 shouldn't. And btw, `objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` changes the shared ObjectMapper so once `toMapIgnoreNull` has been called I'd expect nulls to be also ignored by `toMap`.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that each method call operates independently without affecting each other's settings, you need to create a new ObjectMapper instance within each method call. This way, each method has its own ObjectMapper instance with its own settings, and changes made in one method won't affect the behavior of the other method.

Here is helpful answer to the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37409580/12403892

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing this behavior is because of the way `ObjectMapper` is set up in your `JsonUtil` class. The `ObjectMapper` instance is set up as a static variable, which means it's shared across all invocations of your `toMap` and `toMapIgnoreNull` methods.

The `setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` function changes the state of the `ObjectMapper` – once you call it, all subsequent serializations done with that same `ObjectMapper` will also ignore null values unless you specifically reset it.

You're seeing different results in your `johnOut()` and `jimOut()` because the execution order determines whether the `ObjectMapper` is set to exclude nulls or not.

Here is an improved version of your `JsonUtil` class:

```java
@Slf4j
public class JsonUtil {
    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    static {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
        javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
        objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    }
    
    public static Map<String, Object> toMap(Object obj) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.convertValue(obj, new TypeReference<>() {});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("failed：", e);
            return Map.of();
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> toMapIgnoreNull(Object obj) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper localMapper = objectMapper.copy();
            localMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
            return localMapper.convertValue(obj, new TypeReference<>() {});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("failed：", e);
            return Map.of();
        }
    }
}
```

In the `toMapIgnoreNull` method, I created a local copy of `ObjectMapper` to prevent it from affecting any other invocations of `toMapIgnoreNull` or `toMap`. Now, your `johnOut()` and `jimOut()` methods can be arranged in any order, and they should produce predictable results according to the methods used.

Answer (score 0):

As others already commented your two methods are using the same object mapper and thus are sharing its settings. To fix this, create 2 object mappers and have each method use its own.

However, don't create a copy inside `toMapIgnoreNull()` because that seems wasteful. Instead create another shared instance just for that method.

What also intrigued me is the fact that you always get `null` or never, depending on the order. I'd have expected at least one `password=null` when `johnOut()` is called first. So I checked and it seems `ObjectMapper` is caching some settings which is why after being used for the first time some settings don't take effect (also see [Jackson ObjectMapper setSerializationInclusion() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406817/jackson-objectmapper-setserializationinclusion-not-working)).

That once more reinforces the statement above: if you have different configurations prepare a separate ObjectMapper instance for each config *before* using them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I created another ObjectMapper. XD